# Function App termination during deployment

Tags: azure-functions

We have some function apps that take a few minutes to complete execution. In a situation when a function app is running, we deploy a new version of code the function app gets terminated.

If we use slots during deployment, the running function apps are terminated on slot swap.

Is there a way, so that a running function app can finish its execution while we deploy new code?

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation:

1. If you deploy a new version of function with **different function name** or **changing any parameter** related to the ***function URL*** (https://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/functionname),
   then you'll get error while running the existing function.
2. If you are changing ***just the context in the code*** without modifying any of the ***parameters***, it ***doesn't affect the function execution*** while deploying the new function.

**Case 1:**

- I have created an Azure function app in portal and deployed a dotnet Http Triggered Azure function to it with the Function Name **Function1**.
- I have changed the function name to **Function2** in local.

```cs
[FunctionName("Function2")]  
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(  
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,  
ILogger log)  
{
// code
}
```

- Tried running the existing function while deploying the newly modified function. This led me to the below error.

[image]

**Case 2:**

- In this case, I have just modified the response message without changing the function parameters.

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
 
    string name = req.Query["name"];
 
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
 
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a value in the query string"
        : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
 
    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

- **Able to run the existing function without any errors during parallelly deploying the modified function.**

[image]

- **The response got updated after the deployment.**

[image]